# ITelemetryInitializer not being called in Azure function V4

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, azure-functions

I have an V4 Azure function running .net6 as a isolated process. I want to set the Cloud role name in Application insights so I created class that inherits ITelemetryInitializer.

```
public class MyOwnTelemetryInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
{ 

    public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        telemetry.Context.Cloud.RoleName = "MyAppName";
    }
}
```

Then I inject it in the main function

```
public static void Main()
    {
        var host = new HostBuilder()
            .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
            .ConfigureServices(s =>
            {
                s.AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer, MyOwnTelemetryInitializer >();
                
                
            })
            .Build();

        host.Run();
    }
```

I also set the "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY" in the locl.settings.json

The logging to application insights is working, but the Initialize() in MyOwnTelemetryInitializer never get call. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you using the correct nuget package?  There is a different one for Web and Worker processes.

Comment: @Neil What nuget package? There is one Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Logging.ApplicationInsights but there are no packages for isolated ones (none with Worker in their names), right?

Comment: Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService & Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore are the 2 packages we use on my project. I use exactly the same code as you, and it works fine.

Comment: It seems there is some confusion regarding this issue https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/760
I was able to get the Initialize() called by using AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService() and TelemeryClient.